# Convert float number to int or string

Tags: php, string, floating-point, int

I am retrieving a Facebook ID and I am getting a float:

```
float(1.1262850591603E+16)
```

How could I convert it to int (or string) to use it here?

> http://graph.facebook.com/**1.1262850591603E+16**/picture

I tried intval function, but it returns a wrong result:

```
<?php
intval(1.1262850591603E+16); // returns -1062487752
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are beyond the limit of the php int. You will have to implement your own integer to represent this number :)

Comment: Did you use a  standard PHP Facebook API to get the 'Facebook Id'? Would you please post some sample code that you use?

Comment: @RyanVincent, I am getting data from a third party (Salesforce) webservice...

Comment: Thanks for that clarification - any code that we can look at? What you got - what you did with it? I do not understand where the 'float' came from as 'Id's will be very specific. Normally strings or 'integers' - never floats.

Comment: @RyanVincent you gave me the light... Thank you!

The problem: I was getting data via curl from a ws and json_encoding it.
Php json_encode function has an option: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING that solves the problem.

Thank you again!

Comment: Please post what you found as an answer - it really is very useful. You can accept your own answer. Well spotted. I learned today. thanks.

Comment: Done @RyanVincent, you are helping me like a Jedi today ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution reading the comments :)

The problem: I was retrieving data from a webservice via curl and json_encoding the result. At this point, json_encode converts bigints into floats.

I solved it passing JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING argument to json_encode.

It's documented in PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a string using `strval` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php

```
strval($your_float_variable);
```